# Spring Boot Turbine

Tags: turbine

I tried turbine + hystrix dashboard with Spring boot 2. But i get problem, turbine dashboard only shows : 
Loading ...
I have working Eureka server and application (sends proper hystrix.stream)

When i look at turbine.stream its only

```
: ping
data: {"reportingHostsLast10Seconds":0,"name":"meta","type":"meta","timestamp":1533038381277}
```

I was looking in many questions but i cant get answer.

This is turbine pom file:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.archaius</groupId>
        <artifactId>archaius-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-turbine</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=9090
spring.application.name=turbine-dashboard
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
turbine.app-config=RANDOMNUMBERSERVICE
```

app

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableTurbine
@EnableHystrixDashboard
public class TurbineTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TurbineTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@janusz Please attach a screenshot of your dashboard for more clarity.

If you're seeing this on your screen:
[image]

It could mean:

- You need to hit the endpoint that contains the `@HystrixCommand` annotated function (in your case I'm assuming it is `RANDOMNUMBERSERVICE` app's endpoint) in order to create data for the dashboard to display.
- You have no running instance of serviceId `RANDOMNUMBERSERVICE`
- Check if your clusters are correctly configured: http://localhost:9090/clusters should NOT return  `[]`  on your browser.

If you're seeing this on your screen:
[image]

- Check if your clusters are correctly configured: http://localhost:9090/clusters should NOT return  `[]`  on your browser. Normally this issue is due to inability to access /hystrix.steam from the configured instances but you have stated that that you are already receiving the stream.

I'd suggest using the below in your `application.properties` file could recify this:

```
turbine.appConfig = randomnumberservice
turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig = RANDOMNUMBERSERVICE
```

Finally, make sure the URL you're entering for turbine enabled dahboard is pointing to the port that your dashboard is on.
in your case it should be:

http://localhost:9090/turbine.stream?cluster=yourclustername